# Why can't I set a Unity.UI.Text object to a string?

Tags: string, unity-game-engine, text, type-conversion, integer

So I am trying to create a score counter for my game, and i want it to increment every time and enemy is killed. However when I try and set the score to its previous value + 1 I get an error stating:
`error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.UI.Text' to 'string'`

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class ShieldController : MonoBehaviour
{
    Text score;

    bool shot = false;

    public void LaunchForward(float speed)
    {
        shot = true;
        this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = transform.up * speed;
    }

    void Start() {
        score = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Text").GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
        if (shot) {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            score.text = (int.Parse(score) + 1).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

The text is set to "0" at the start.
Why am I getting this error?

Comment: `(int.Parse(score.text)` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are parsing the score object which is the UnityEngine UI Text component, instead change it to :

```
score.text = (int.Parse(score.text) + 1).ToString();
```

I would also recommend having a separate score integer variable to store the score.
So you would have **scoreText** as UnityEngine UI Text & **score** as Integer then you could do something like:

```
score++;

scoreText.text = $"{score}";
```

**Side Note:**

Please do not use these kind of assignments :

```
score = GameObject.Find("Canvas/Text").GetComponent<Text>();
```

For this specific case, you could assign the text component from UnityEditor by adding this:

```
[SerializeField] private Text score;
```

And get rid of what you're doing in the Start function.